# WordPress with Nginx + PHP-FPM sometimes slow where slowlog pointing to wp-config.php (PHP 8.1)

Tags: nginx, php, performance, php-fpm, wordpress

I have a recent WordPress 6 installation with MariaDB and PHP 8 FPM running on Docker. Sometimes, request on the frontend have a slow response time on the main HTML document. In this example, one of the category pages took 1,8 seconds:

[image]

Since all the queries took only 0,06s and according to the plugin, we have no external HTTP calls, I can't explain why this happens. Normally we have ~300-400ms, which is still a bit high, but far more acceptable than ~1.8s.

The slowlog trace of PHP FPM just shows

```
php    | [30-Jul-2022 10:50:46] WARNING: [pool www] child 26, script '/www/index.php' (request: "GET /wp/index.php?category/software/") executing too slow (1.170804 sec), logging
php    | [30-Jul-2022 10:50:46] NOTICE: child 26 stopped for tracing
php    | [30-Jul-2022 10:50:46] NOTICE: about to trace 26
php    | [30-Jul-2022 10:50:46]  [pool www] pid 26
php    | script_filename = /www/index.php
php    | [0x00007f86db6129c0] [INCLUDE_OR_EVAL]() /www/wp-config.php:110
php    | [0x00007f86db612720] [INCLUDE_OR_EVAL]() /www/wp-load.php:50
php    | [0x00007f86db612190] [INCLUDE_OR_EVAL]() /www/wp-blog-header.php:13
php    | [0x00007f86db612090] [INCLUDE_OR_EVAL]() /www/index.php:17
php    | [30-Jul-2022 10:50:46] NOTICE: finished trace of 26
```

which doesn't seem usefull to me, since this line in `wp-config.php` just contains

```
110 require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

and `wp-settings.php` itself is a very huge script, including tons of other php files. So I don't see a way to analyze what's causing this massive slowdowns.

My PHP-FPM configuration

```
log_level = notice
error_log = /proc/self/fd/2


[www]
; if we send this to /proc/self/fd/1, it never appears
access.log = /proc/self/fd/2
;access.log = /dev/null

clear_env = no

user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

;pm = dynamic
;pm.max_children = 40
;pm.start_servers = 20
;pm.min_spare_servers = 10
;pm.max_spare_servers = 25
;pm.max_requests = 200

pm = static
pm.max_children = 40
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_spare_servers = 20
pm.max_requests = 100
; https://www.kevinhooke.com/2018/02/27/nginx-php5-fpm-response-lag-on-first-requests/
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s
pm.status_path = /status

slowlog = /proc/self/fd/2
request_slowlog_timeout = 1s

catch_workers_output = yes
env[TMP] = /tmp
env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
env[TEMP] = /tmp
```

Since this is a test environment, there is no external traffic. I also verified this on the PHP-FPM status page, where most of the workers are idle. Sometimes the page loads are even slower (up to 8s), it depends from time to time, which looks like a load issue, but it can't be. Even the bare metal server where those containers are running, has a very low load:

```
Load average: 0.38 0.60 0.59
```

#### EDIT

I noticed that the page load times are much faster, when I restart Nginx + PHP-FPM (both are in a single compose file, the MariaDB is in a seperate one). But this doesn't fix the problem permanently, after some time it became slow again. I already tried to decrease `pm.max_requests = 100`, it was 500 before, but didn't fix the problem.

Comment: is this wordpress a business related site?

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was a stupid mistake which I made: Since it's a test environment, I reduced the memory limit for the PHP container in the `docker-compose.yml` to just 1 GB

```
services:
  test-php:
    # ...
    mem_limit: 1G
```

It was set to 2 GB before, because average script memory consumption * child processes would was calculated to 1,7 GB for the productive installation. I forget about this for the test env, so the following happens: PHP spawns multiple processes and doesn't free the memory. This fills the container memory after some requests, which leads to slow page loading times.

This was very confusing, since after some time I also saw MySQLi errors in the logs, which lead me to had a look at the database, which was misleading. It was just the call to the database, or the config in the posted log entry, where the memory of the container was *full* by the limit.